# NDepend - how to run a report on number of methods having and not having an attribute

Tags: ndepend, cqlinq

I would like to run a report on how many methods in a particular assembly and its sub-assemblies have and do not have certain attribute. Can you write to me a sample code for this? What are the reporting options? I need to run this report every night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write something like:

```
(from m in Application.Assemblies.WithNameLike("^MyAssembly").ChildMethods()
 where m.HasAttribute("NamespaceA.AttributeA") &&
       m.HasAttribute("NamespaceB.AttributeB") &&
      !m.HasAttribute("NamespaceC.AttributeC")
 select m).Count()
```

Note that the aggregate call to `Count()`, that can be removed if you wish to list methods instead of counting them.

> I need to run this report every night.

Here is the relevant documentation:

- [Reporting CQLinq Rules violation](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLRule)
- [Reporting groups of CQLinq Queries](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_CI_Report.aspx#CQLQuery)